# Pygame: trying to get the whole sprite to cross a boundary instead of just the top left pixel

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my sprite move according to the astar pathfinding algorithm. However, after I implemented it, I realised that the movement of the sprite is only in accordance to the top left pixel. That means that if the algorithm tells it to move up after crossing a boundary, it will do so once the top left pixel crosses that boundary. However, this means that the entire sprite has not actually crossed, resulting in a collision if there is an obstacle just above it. Is there any way to tell it to move left more before moving up][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PeVK.png)

```
def astar_ghost(pac,ghost):
    maze=astar.create_maze(screen_width,screen_height,obstacles) #creates a maze of 0s and 1s. The 1s represent the obstacles

    start=(ghost.gridloc[0],ghost.gridloc[1])
    end=(ghost.goal_node[0],ghost.goal_node[1])
    goal_node=astar.astar(maze,start,end)

    if goal_node==None:
        pass
    else:
        ghost.goal_node=goal_node

    game=True

    if ghost.goal_node[0]<ghost.gridloc[0]:#left
         print('move left')

         game=collision(pac,ghost) #collision is another function that checks for collision and returns True or False. If False, the game will be over
         ghost.left=True
         ghost.right=False
         ghost.up=False
         ghost.down=False

     elif ghost.goal_node[0]>ghost.gridloc[0]:#right
         print('move right')

         game=collision(pac,ghost)
         ghost.left=False
         ghost.right=True
         ghost.up=False
         ghost.down=False

    elif ghost.goal_node[1]<ghost.gridloc[1]:#up
         print('move up')

         game=collision(pac,ghost)
         ghost.left=False
         ghost.right=False
         ghost.up=True
         ghost.down=False

    elif ghost.goal_node[1]>ghost.gridloc[1]:#down
        print('move down')

        game=collision(pac,ghost)
        ghost.left=False
        ghost.right=False
        ghost.up=False
        ghost.down=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking a few different questions here. I'll answer here to what I think you're trying to ask: **Is there a way to check if an entire sprite has crossed a boundary, instead of just the top-left corner?**. So, my answer (note this will only work if your boundary line is linear): You need to check each of the corners individually, then, if all of them have returned `True`, then you move on. Example:

```
def collision(sprite1, boundary):
    def internal_collision(point, boundary):
        ... # The actual math happens here, returns True/False
    corners = []
    for h in [0, 1]:
        for j in [0, 1]:
            corners.append([sprite1.rect.x+(h*sprite1.rect.width),
                            sprite1.rect.y+(j*sprite1.rect.height)])
    corner_check = []
    for corner in corners:
        corner_check.append(internal_collision(corner, boundary))
    return all(corner_check)
```

I don't know how your code works, so I've tried to keep this as malleable and understandable as possible, so you can re-implement it in your own code.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot!